# Seach txt File for a keyword like [word & random number]

Tags: python, search, full-text-search

I have this code:

```
with open("Text.txt") as txtFile:
    for num, line in enumerate(txtFile, 1):
        if "ABC" in line:
            keyWord = "ABC"
            keyWord = "#" + keyWord + "#"
```

I want to search `Text.txt` for a keyword that contains a random number, that looks like this:

Keyword = [**Word** & **random Number**] or [ABC-1] / [ABC-1234]

The "Word" part is always the same but the number is up to 4 decimals (1-9999).

When the keyword is found, i want to highlight it like this:

ABC-1 to #ABC-1# with

```
keyWord = "ABC-1"

keyWord = "#" + keyWord + "#"
```

**Question:**

How can i search the file for ABC-1 and not just ABC

Comment: use [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html): `ABC-\d{1,4}`. You can test your regular expression in online site, e.g., [reg101](https://regex101.com/) or even generate the code for you.

Comment: 1. word and number should be separated by dash ?

2. Is number range [1-1000] or [1-9999] ?

Comment: 1. Yes seperated by dash and 2. the range is 1-9999.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using regular expressions and backreferences

```py
import re

with open("text.txt", 'r') as txt_file:
    with open("new_text.txt", 'w') as new_file:
        p = re.compile('(ABC-\d{1,4})')
        for line in txt_file:
            new_line = p.sub(r'#\1#', line)
            new_file.write(new_line)
```

Comment: It worked, but when I have 2 keywords, like "ABC-" and "DEF-", how do I change the code to get both of them changed to the # format?

Comment: use `p = re.compile('((?:ABC|DEF)-\d{1,4})')`. The inner group is a non-capturing group so it is ignored when backreferencing.